# Limit returned fields in Json schema

Tags: json, rest, go, odata

I have a requirement to allow a client to only request a subset of fields from a large json schema. I have done this using ODATA and their concept of [$select](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) (I like a lot about ODATA. Except the lack of adoption) I know I can spin my own solution but feel there must be other open source solutions I can use or use as a base. ( my service is in go)

Does anyone know of something similar? Common conventions?

Adding some clarification:

Say I have a schema like the following:

```
{
    "status": {
        "enum": [
            "active",
            "inactive"
        ]
    },
    "lastModified": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time"
    },
    "userId": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "username": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    }
}
```

By default, a GET to our User resource will return all of these fields. What I would like is a way for a client say they just want something like the following:

```
{
   "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Using Odata you can specify this with a $select querystring argument. Ideally, I'd like to have a client specify the schema they would like and we just pass the full schema through a, sort of, filter that does just this each time. But, I feel that will likely be something I'll have to code myself. But, in the short-term, if there is a way to have a client specify the fields they want in this way per request, they would be satisfied until we get something a bit more robust.

Comment: Do you want to allow the client specific fields and ignored the rest of the fields  ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood  your question correctly you want to reveal the client specific fields.
If thats the case you can use  [Json tags](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)    like that.

```
type FileMD struct {
FileName string `json:"filename"`
FileSize int    `json:"filesize"`
FileMD5  string **`json:"-"`**//this wil ignore the FileMD5 field
```

}

Comment: Not quite, but close. See my added detail above. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't  use this  before but  u can validate your json with that 
https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema